# There was a network error (file:///android_asset/www/skinloader.html) worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a simple Hello World application in Worklight and want to run it in my Genymotion emulator. The application loads but I get this error message: there was a network error `(file:///android_asset/www/skinloader.html)` and when I press OK the application closes.

I have not done anything with the files and it also failed to load the default Hello World app (downloaded from IBM) with the same error message.

Anyone got a clue why this occurs?
have a look this please help me

Comment: Worklight does not officially support Genymotion; if you test with the Google supplied emulator, does it work?

Comment: @IdanAdar I did set up an AVD in Eclipse but the screen is only black (the AVD had the default settings). My colleague got it to work with Genymotion.

Comment: Did you try to consult with your colleague then? This is not a Worklight problem...

Comment: We've just tried this in the local Android emulator and we see the same issue. The skinLoader.html reference indicates that this is Worklight-related. Still investigating...

Comment: Please add more details: worklight version and build number, android image used, android api level used, define "simple" (is it dojo-simple or simple-simple?, what's "simple" about it?

Comment: I solved it by removing and uninstalling Android SDK and Eclipse and by downloading Eclipse with the built in Android SDK and by redownloading Worklight to Eclipse. What we did figure out was when I checked inside the .apk file the skinloader.html were missing. Don´t know why.

Comment: @RashwanLazkani, don't keep this as a comment - please supply it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing and uninstalling Android SDK and Eclipse and by downloading Eclipse with the built in Android SDK and by redownloading Worklight to Eclipse. What we did figure out was when I checked inside the .apk (changed it to .zip and navigated to the www folder) the skinloader.html file were missing. Don´t know why.